# Best way to instantiate a class form a properties template C#?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of template classes imported from a JSON file.

```
BfPropsGroup = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(groupString);
BfPropsTransport = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(vehicleString);
BfPropsLeader = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(leaderString);
```

Now what i'd like to do is to instantiate classes based on those like so :

```
Player.BfProps = new BattlefieldProps() {
    prop1 = BfPropsGroup.prop1
    prop2 = BfPropsGroup.prop2
    //...}
```

There's about 15-20 props each time and the number of Json imported classes is gonna grow too. If there's any solution to do that better, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up implementing a method that assigns the Json instead of calling new every time. like so :

```
public static BattlefieldProps GetBattlefieldPropsGroup()
{
    var output = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(groupString);
    return output;
}

public static BattlefieldProps GetBattlefieldPropsTransport()
{
    var output = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(vehicleString);
    return output;
}

public static BattlefieldProps GetBattlefieldPropsLeader()
{
    var output = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(leaderString);
    return output;
}
 

BfPropsGroup = GetBattlefieldPropsGroup();
BfPropsTransport = GetBattlefieldPropsTransport();
BfPropsLeader = GetBattlefieldPropsLeader();
```

and then again when I need it for the players :

```
Player.BfProps = GetBattlefieldPropsGroup();
```

Comment: I honestly don't really understand your issue or solution either ^^ `implementing a method that assigns the Json instead of calling new every time` well the `JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(groupString);` already returns a `BattlefieldProps` so why didn't you simply do `Player.BfProps = JsonUtility.FromJson<BattlefieldProps>(groupString);` in the first place?

Comment: I just didn't really understand how FromJson() really worked.
To elaborate a bit: 
I need dynamic instances on one side as actual player stats,
and on the other side I need classes that store the base data (the ones from the Json files). I got used to using the "static" ones a lot, so I didn't really think back on my process when asking that. @derHugo